# Which Windows System Property returns actual path from SQL Windows Search

Tags: c#, sql, windows-search

I am querying Windows Search using SQL

```
SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay 
FROM SystemIndex 
WHERE SCOPE = 'file:C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu' 
  AND System.ItemName LIKE '%remote%'
```

And this is what is returned with the user friendly path

```
Remote Desktop Connection.lnk;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories\Remote Desktop Connection.lnk;
```

The real path should be `Accessories` NOT `Windows Accessories`

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\
```

How do I get the real path from Windows Search?

All `System.*` properties seem to only return the 'friendly path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like System.ItemUrl gives me what I need

```
Remote Desktop Connection.lnk;file:C:/ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Remote Desktop Connection.lnk;
```